# MySQL query, Most recent values from a historical table of values

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I have a table with historical values. Every time one of the value is updated a copy of that value is added to this table indexed by "request_id"

I am looking for away to get the most updated values for each "request_id" without having to retrieve the entire table.

**Current table:**

```
ID | Modified | request_id | value 
-------------------------------------
 1 |       10 |          1 | "one"
 2 |       15 |          1 | "two"
 3 |       15 |          2 | "three"
 4 |       18 |          1 | "fore"
 5 |       25 |          3 | "five"
 6 |       36 |          1 | "six"
```

**Result table**

```
ID | Modified | request_id | value 
-------------------------------------
 3 |       15 |          2 | "three"
 5 |       25 |          3 | "five"
 6 |       36 |          1 | "six"
```

I am using PHP and SQLite if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite? Hmz, can't test but try this:

```
SELECT value FROM your_table GROUP BY request_id ORDER BY modifier;
```

If you have any issues with this query, post the error and we'll try and fix.

Comment: +1 I never knew about the GROUP BY command... very nice. I will have to remember this one.

Comment: @MasterZ distinct works on the entire row set, meaning if you select the value and the request_id, you'd get all the rows, since no 2 rows have the same request_id and value... just a hint :)

Comment: That is a good solution. I thought GROUP BY like this would not work with SQLite (Postgre mindset) :)

Comment: @Asterisk I checked the docs immediately after the post, it seems to support it. I was surprised to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

I may have the syntax slightly wrong but this should point you in the right direction.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT request_id FROM history_table ORDER BY modified"
```

This will only grab one of each request_id so you do not get duplicates.

Comment: do `ORDER BY modified` and it will be closer to working. Distinct isn't as good in other situations similar to this though. You need to get the value!

Comment: I made the change. Thanks. :)
Yeah I think I have only used DISTINCT once ever, but it is useful in this case I think.

Comment: The problem with this is that it does not return the row data. it only returns the DISTINCT values of request_id

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM test_table t1
WHERE t1.modified IN (SELECT max(Modified)
                      FROM test_table t2
                      WHERE t2.request_id = t1.request_id
                      GROUP By t2.request_id)
```

Note: this is not a very efficient way of doing it, since it has correlated subquery.

**EDIT: without correlation, for PostgreSQL**

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE (request_id, modified) IN (SELECT request_id, max(modified)
                                 FROM test
                                 GROUP BY request_id);
```